# TextView in Fragment will not update

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-inflate

I have a TextView in a fragment that i am trying to update from MainActivity.
I am using an interface to communicate with MainActivity, and MainActivity is calling a public method in the fragment.

I used onCreateView() and onActivityCreate() to get the TextView but both have given the same result. When i debug the app the newFact variable of the updateFact() method in the fragment is being set from MainActivity but the TextView does not change.

The fragment is not part of MainActivity and is loading into the FrameLayout of the activity in the Activities onCreate() method.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
    FragmentContract{

Toolbar mToolbar;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private FactFragment factFragment;
private RandomFragment randomFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    factFragment = new FactFragment();

    //show FactFragment when app is opened
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
            new FactFragment()).commit();

}//onCreate()




//overriden methods of FragmentContract
@Override
public void randomSwipe() {

}

@Override
public void leftToRight() {
    if(factFragment != null){
        Toast.makeText(this,"left to right in main",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        factFragment.updateFact("from main");
        //factFragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.factFragTV);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "fragment is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**FactFragment**

```
public class FactFragment extends Fragment {
    //communicate between fragment and activity
    private FragmentContract communicator;
    private TextView fact;


    public FactFragment(){}


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        //assign listener variable (communicator) and check if
        //MainActivity implements the interface
        if(activity instanceof FragmentContract){
            //assign listener variable
            communicator = (FragmentContract) activity;
            Log.d("tag", "listener assigned");
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException(activity.toString() + "must implement FragmentContract");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //this method is used to instantiate the views
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fact, container, false);
        factBackground = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.factImageFrag);
        fact = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.factFragTV);


        //listen for swipe gestures
        final GestureDetector gesture = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                        final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
                        final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
                        final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
                        try {
                            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                                return false;
                            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "left To right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                communicator.leftToRight();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // nothing
                        }
                        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                    }
                });

        rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gesture.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }//onCreateView()


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        fact = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.factFragTV);
    }

    public void updateFact(String newFact){
        fact.setText(newFact);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "updateFact called in fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("tag","Update()" + newFact);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        communicator = null;
    }
}//FactFragment
```

**Interface**

```
    public interface FragmentContract {

    void randomSwipe();

    void leftToRight();//-->
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making mistake here

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
            new FactFragment()).commit();
```

You should use `factFragment` instead of `new FactFragment()` in `replace`.

Below is the updated code of using fragmentManager that you can use as a fix of this problem.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                factFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong approach to communicate between activity to fragment. You can't communicate with fragment via a public method safely.

Rather:

1.Make another interface with only one method, named `void updateFact(String newFact)`

```
public interface Listener {

    void updateFact(String newFact);

}
```

2.Implement the interface on the Fragment and Override the method

```
public class FactFragment extends Fragment implements Listener{
.
.
@Override
    public void updateFact(String newFact){
      fact.setText(newFact);
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "updateFact called in fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Log.d("tag","Update()" + newFact);
    }


}
```

3.Create a global variable of the interface and typecast the Fragment object to a variable of interface.
4. When needed communicate via the listener.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FragmentContract{

private Listener listener;
.
.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
.
factFragment = new FactFragment();
listener = (Listener) factFragment; 

getSupportFragmentManager(). beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
        factFragment).commit();

} 
@Override
public void leftToRight() {
if(listener != null){
    Toast.makeText(this,"left to right in main",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    listener.updateFact("from main");
}else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "fragment is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this topic's issue for days.

TL;DR- It is a different direction of the above comments, but if it helps anyone in the future - make sure where you use **static** variables.

Those are saved (by their nature) in a manner that won't update on a fragment
reload, or onResume() or onViewCreate() etc..

So if you are using static variables across a few fragments/activities and change or update them, they would only update their value when the application completely closed and reopened in my case.